# WP: How do I change foreground color of Pivot title to theme color or default color

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot, foreground

I want to change Pivot item's title color to match theme color. But I also want to change it back to default color (Black or White depending on background setting in Settings) at some condition. How should I do it. Appreciated!

```
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="pivot_vip">
<phone:PivotItem.Header>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Artists, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
</phone:PivotItem.Header>

private void View_selection_changed(

    ...

    PivotItem currentItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;
    if (currentItem != null)
    {
        if (current_view == HanlderType.EVIPHandler)
        {
            (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = ??? //Theme color
        }
        else
        {
            (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = **???** //whatever default 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PhoneForegroundBrush` resource key which will be either white or black depending on current system theme.

```cs
(currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = 
           (SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I was changing question a little bit. How about change color to default title? For example, default is black or white (depending on the settings in Settings/Theme/Background[Black/White])

Comment: My answer will give you the default title color depending on current theme.